# How to layout Graphviz / dot layout and order question

Tags: graphviz, dot, pygraphviz

I'm trying to use dot notation and set the order of the items. in the example below I would like FLIP/FLOPA to be on top and FLIP/FLOPB on the bottom. It would also be good to line everything up.

[image]

I'm a bit confused how invisible edges might work?

this is where im at:

---

```
digraph G {
graph [pad ="1", rankdir = LR, splines=ortho];
size = "16.66,8.33!"; // 1200x600 at 72px/in, "!" to force 
ratio = "fill";


node[shape=record];


flipa[label="FLIPA", height=3];
flopa[label="FLOPA", height=3];


flipb[label="FLIPB", height=3];
flopb[label="FLOPB", height=3];


source1[shape=rarrow];
source2[shape=rarrow];


sink1[shape=rarrow];
sink2[shape=rarrow];


source1 -> flipa;
flipa -> flopa [label="red" color=red,penwidth=3.0];
flipa -> flopa [label="blue" color=blue,penwidth=3.0];
flopa -> sink1;


source2 -> flipb;
flipb -> flopb [label="red" color=red,penwidth=3.0]; 
flipb -> flopb [label="blue" color=blue,penwidth=3.0];
flopb -> sink2;




label="Graph";
labelloc=top;
labeljust=left; 


}
```

---

Thanks in advance

Neil

Answer (score 0):

The order in which you mention nodes in layout is important.

If you have horizontal layout (`rankdir=LR`), the nodes appear in your layout from bottom to top, look at this, for example:

```
digraph {
    rankdir=LR

    node1
    node2
    node3
}
```

This results in:

[image]

Now if we reverse the order:

```
digraph {
    rankdir=LR

    node3
    node2
    node1
}
```

We get this:

[image]

PS: I don't recommend using ortho splines, they may cause all sorts of artifacts, including very poor handling of edge labels. You problems with lining up may be caused by them. Even though when I compile your code on my machine, the nodes are lined up correctly.

---

To answer your question in the comments:

**How to implement parallel edges without `splines=ortho`**
But let me warn you, it is very ugly.

In graphviz you can use [HTML-like syntax](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/shapes.html#html) to define some structures, most important of them being tables. Any old enough frontender will tell you that you can design almost **anything** using tables. I use them a lot when work with graphviz.

What you can do in your situation: instead of your plain rectangular nodes place a table with three rows. Top row and bottom row are going to be empty. The middle one will contain your label: FLIPA or FLOPA.

Next you assign `port` attribute to all cells. This way you will be able to connect **specific rows** of tables together using the [headport](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html#d:headport) and [tailport](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html#d:tailport) (or their synonims, the colon-syntax, which I used in example below).

Here's the example:

```
digraph G {
graph [pad ="1", rankdir = LR];
size = "16.66,8.33!"; // 1200x600 at 72px/in, "!" to force 
ratio = "fill";

node[shape=record];

flipb[
    shape=plain
    label=<
        <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellborder="0">
            <tr>
                <td height="80" port="upper"> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="80" port="middle">FLIPB</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="80" port="bottom"> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    >
];
flopb[
    shape=plain
    label=<
        <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellborder="0">
            <tr>
                <td height="80" port="upper"> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="80" port="middle">FLOPB</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="80" port="bottom"> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    >
];

flipa[
    shape=plain
    label=<
        <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellborder="0">
            <tr>
                <td height="80" port="upper"> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="80" port="middle">FLIPA</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="80" port="bottom"> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    >
];
flopa[
    shape=plain
    label=<
        <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellborder="0">
            <tr>
                <td height="80" port="upper"> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="80" port="middle">FLOPA</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="80" port="bottom"> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    >
];

source1[shape=rarrow];
source2[shape=rarrow];

sink1[shape=rarrow];
sink2[shape=rarrow];

source1 -> flipa;
flipa:upper -> flopa:upper [label="red" color=red,penwidth=3.0];
flipa:bottom -> flopa:bottom [label="blue" color=blue,penwidth=3.0];
flopa -> sink1;

source2 -> flipb;
flipb:upper -> flopb:upper [label="red" color=red,penwidth=3.0]; 
flipb:bottom -> flopb:bottom [label="blue" color=blue,penwidth=3.0];
flopb -> sink2;

label="Graph";
labelloc=top;
labeljust=left;

}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks for your help, ive realised playing around that order is important.... am I right in thinking its circular? Anyway the reason I was using ortho splines was because the lines we sitting on each other. Is there another mode?

Comment: @NeilBernard you can control where the edge starts from and where it comes into with attributes "headport" and "tailport". Unfortunately you can direct them only to corners and to the middle of the side, there's no in between, I suffer from this a lot too. If you absolutely need the edges be straight and apart and using ortho splines is not an option, there are some other solutions, but they are UGLY. You can use a table with two cells and point edges to the middle of cells.

Comment: to create a table is that a DOT thing or do I need to create an HTML table? for my application what you suggest might just work.

Comment: @NeilBernard I've updated the answer with the tables example and explanation